# Change Enter key to Tab key in silverlight forms

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

how can i change enter key in silverlight forms to tab key.i use the following code in winforms but i don't know how can i implement this in silverlight!

```
/// <summary>
/// Change Enter key To Tab Key
/// </summary>
/// <param name="msg"></param>
/// <param name="keyData"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (msg.Msg == 256 && keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Execute an alternative action: here we tabulate in order to focus on the next control in the formular             
        if (ActiveControl.ToString().Contains("System.Windows.Forms.Button") ||
            ActiveControl.ToString().Contains("DevComponents.DotNetBar.ButtonX"))

            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

        // return true to stop any further interpretation of this key action
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: I did not put all of your code in the example below.. just wanted to show you how you should return the expected results feel free to let us know if the code worked.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverlight we have KeyDown Event on that we can check that which key have been pressed. You can write a function in KeyDown event and in that check if e.key == Enter if The Enter key presses than made focus to the Desired TextBox to which you want.

Comment: in what regards does it not work..? be more specific.. this should work.. but let me double check something..

Comment: ok.thank you.it 's work perfect! but can i implement in SendKeys in Silverlight?!

Comment: try this link http://justinangel.net/CuttingEdgeSilverlight4ComFeatures and do a search for this title on the form Feature #4: Emulate user input

Comment: yes! it 's work in out of browser application.thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but anyone viewing this thread - It is possible to use TAB key when you press ENTER by using AutomationFactory in Silverlight 5. I did this by writing a behaviour where you listen to KeyDown and pass in TAB Key. The application has to be running in OOB mode. You can attach this behaviour to textbox in Blend.

```
public class EnterKeyPropertyChangeBehaviour : Behavior<DependencyObject>
{
    public EnterKeyPropertyChangeBehaviour()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        // Insert code that you would want run when the Behavior is attached to an object.
        var fe = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null) fe.KeyDown += fe_KeyDown;

    }

    void fe_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            using (dynamic shell = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"))
            {
                shell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
            }   

        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        // Insert code that you would want run when the Behavior is removed from an object.
        var fe = AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null) fe.KeyDown -= fe_KeyDown;
    }

}
```